# How can I change the url that a cypress test run on Github uses when making a request to the server?

Tags: github, testing, automated-tests, cypress, github-actions

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoD4r.png)

I'm writing a test for my ReactJS project but on github, since the test is running on localhost it gets the server url as local url, how can I edit it to make a request to the live server ?(I'm using Cypress)

Comment: Have you set the baseUrl config for cypress? https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#e2e

Comment: Please try and copy/paste relevant code snippets instead of linking screenshots. When you do use screenshots, please make sure to provide an alternative description to make sure everybody understands what the image is about.